# How to put an dictionary to an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to split the `History_Data` with `,` and put into an dictionary , then put the dictionary to a one dimension array then access them . But it seems have some error . How can I solve that?

here is my code

```
History_Data = ("2004/01/20,000006,29,28,13,33,34,32,43",
                "2004/01/18,000005,36,22,44,34,46,29,37",
                "2004/01/16,000004,02,13,34,44,06,40,14",
                "2004/01/14,000003,29,28,13,33,34,32,43",
                "2004/01/12,000002,32,15,14,29,39,20,43",
                "2004/01/10,000001,30,29,18,34,19,28,12")

Dataset = ()
for Line in History_Data:
    Item = {}
    Parts = Line.split(",") 
    Item['date'] = Parts[0]
    Item['serial'] = Parts[1]
    Item['numbers'] = Parts[2:len(Parts)]
    Dataset.append(Item)

for Element in Dataset:
    print(Element)
```

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\1.py", line 18, in <module>
    Dataset.append(Item)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: 1. Your Dataset should be a `list` instead of a `tuple` (switch the parentheses `()` with brackets `[]`) 2. You don't need to specify the length of Parts on your slice, it can be just `Item['numbers'] = Parts[2:]`

Comment: -1, Please read what the error tells you and try to understand it. Asking stackoverflow every single time you get an error message is problematic, not only for us, but for you as well since you can learn so much about your program if you just read the traceback and the errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tuple` is an immutable type in Python so gets no method `append`. For your need, use a list, `Dataset = []`, not a tuple, `Dataset = ()`.